# How could I use nodemcu to send a ping( monitor spec ip)?

Tags: lua, esp8266, nodemcu

I'm using an esp8266 development board for development. At present, I need to implement a ping like function, but I searched around and found no code to implement.
I'm using the firmware of nodemcu, using Lua as the programming language. Do you have any tips? Thank you first.

ps:
More specifically, the function I want to implement is to monitor whether a fixed IP is online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A ping command is not available in NodeMCU at the moment. There is a [net_info module waiting for release](https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware/pull/2854) though.

Until then you have to use a workaround using other functions from existing modules.

https://openamp.wordpress.com/2016/12/21/alternate-to-sending-ping-from-nodemcu-lua-sdk/

Comment: Somehow, it can do ping telephone, but when I test lan-pc ,it  failed...   More exactly, the lan-pc  Ip.

Comment: Well, it's a good walkgroud although, and I'm waiting for the "real ping"...